# Исключение ArgumentException: Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен

Tags: c#

возникла ошибка ArgumentException: Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен  при добавлении словаря
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам словарь, при котором вознила ошибка.

```
   public static Dictionary<string, string> portrait_screenOrientation = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""fullUser\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorLandscape\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""landscape\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorLandscape\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorPortrait\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""user\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""locked\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

           {@"android:screenOrientation=\""fullSensor\""",
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},
        };
```

Comment: О чем вопрос? Найти Вам повторяющиеся ключи? `@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorLandscape\"""`

Comment: припустим они повторяются. Я так понимаю лиш можно использовать каждый раз новый ключ. Здесь немного досадно, ибо в плане использовать таике же самые ключи, в новом словаре, но с другим значением. Нужно что-то другое придумать для реализации? Да?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Ключ в словаре - это уникальный идентификатор. Ключи не могут повторяться в одном и том же словаре. В разных словарях могут быть одинаковые ключи.

Comment: спасибо, это, то что нужно. Вопрос можно удалить.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> portrait_screenOrientation = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""fullUser\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorLandscape\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""landscape\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  //{@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorLandscape\""",
  // "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""sensorPortrait\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""user\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""locked\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},

  {@"android:screenOrientation=\""fullSensor\""",
    "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\""},
};
```

Comment: блин, я невнимательный.., недосмотрел